# Entity Framework one-to-one relationship between multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I have three entities that need to be linked. In my scenario, I have three tables `users`, `stores` and `accounts`.

Both users and stores can have zero or one account and each account should be either for a store or a user (see image below).

I need a one-to-one relationship between user-account and store-account. Since one-to-one relationship force the model to use one key, the user and store Ids might have conflict.

Is there any solution for this in Entity Framework or do I have a flaw in my design?

[image: one-to-one relationship between multiple tables]

Comment: Possibly a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493229/multiple-yet-mutually-exclusive-foreign-keys-is-this-the-way-to-go

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to use intermediate tables user_account and store_account, that would store only keys. This way you can enforce any logic you want.